# Creating a 2D Array from a Text File and Finding Average

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2D array from numbers in a text file, that can be printed and the average is found of each column. Note: I get an error saying "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to int" on "int rows" and "int columns". Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Example Text File:

3

4

6 4 2 12

3 5 6 0

11 0 3 0

Example Output:

Array of scores:

[6, 4, 2, 12]

[3, 5, 6, 0]

[11, 0, 3, 0]

Average score of each assignment:

Assignment #1 Average: 6.66666666666

Assignment #2 Average: 9.0

Assignment #3 Average: 3.66666666666

Assignment #4 Average: 4.0

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Scores {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file containing the scores?");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    //TODO: read in the values for the number of students and number of assignments using the Scanner on the file
    //TODO: create a 2-D to store all the scores and read them all in using the Scanner on the file
    int rows = fileScan.nextLine();
    int columns = fileScan.nextLine();

    int [][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
      while(fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
         for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            String[] line = fileScan.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) {
               myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
            }
         }
      }


    System.out.println("Array of scores:");
    //TODO: print the entire array, row by row, using Arrays.toString()
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));

    System.out.println("Average score of each assignment:");
    //TODO: compute and print the average on each assignment
   double total=0;
    int totallength,assignment;
    for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<myArray[i].length;j++) {
            total+=myArray[i][j];
            totallength++;
        System.out.println("Assignment #" + assignment++ + " Average: " + (total/totallength));
        }
    }
    fileScan.close(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scanner.nextLine() returns a String, not an int. You can try something like `int rows = fileScan.nextInt()` or `int rows = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine());`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `rows` and `columns` are Strings when you read them from the file.  You need to convert them to Integers before you can use them as array indices.  So do something like this:

```
int rows = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine());
int columns = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine());
```